# How to "enter" the selected folder in the vertical wildmenu?

Tags: neovim

When using the vertical file/folder wild menu (ex: pressing `Tab` after `:e`  or `:cd` ) and focused on a folder, is there a way to map a key to "move" inside that folder, and pick one of it's children ? If I press `Enter`, that is considered the "final answer", and the wildmenu is dismissed.

Comment: in Vim it is `Cursor-Right`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt doesn't seem to be working in `neovim`, by default `<Right>` seems to just focus the next option

Answer (score 1):

So after some trial and error, this seems to do the trick:

```
set wildcharm=<C-z>
cnoremap <Right> <Space><BS><Right><C-z>
cnoremap <expr> <Up> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<Up>"
cnoremap <expr> <Down> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Down>"
```

- `<Up>`/`<Down>` selects the item above/below the currently selected one, when there is a menu open. If there is no menu, cycles between commands starting with the currently entered command (default behaviour)
- pressing `<Right>`:

  - with a folder selected: closes current menu, opens a new one with files/folders inside the previously selected folder, and selects the first item - but you can still use `<Up>`/`<Down>`/`<Tab>` to change the selected item, and if on a folder, can press `<Right>` to enter it
  - with a file selected: will simply close the menu - but you'll still have to confirm the choice by pressing `Enter`
- to finalise selection, press `Enter`

Tested in `neovim v0.8.0-dev (6613f58ce)`; doesn't seem to be working in vim (8.1.3741)

Answer (score 0):

By default the same keys are used for both horizontal and vertical menu. That is, `<Left>` and `<Right>` to move selection and `<Up>` and `<Down>` to move between levels.

For this reason, I'd rather recommend to `set wop-=pum` and stick to horizontal menu layout.

Comment: They can be remapped though; horizontal can be quite restrictive, especially when you have long file/folder names - the available space fills up quite quickly